# What is the name of the job who represents a family trust to manage fixed assets

Tags: single-word-requests

Hi I'm hiring a manager for managing some fixed assets, mostly real estate, for a family trust. The person will be tasked to fix some real estate, then do some major upgrades, and collect rent from tenant businesses. He submits development plans to the council as an employee of the trust; he negotiates with the building construction companies and architects; he represents the family trust to engage a lawyer to sue the person who damaged the real estate in the first place; he let the vehicles owned by the family trust to the businesses. He hires cleaners, drivers, gardeners or rental management company (for the properties whose tenant is not a business but residents).

I hope to have a one-word name for the job because such a job existed since the first person who acquired more fixed assets than he can manage himself, which is a common situation in every civilisation in history; there must have been a word for it.

"Trustee" would be close, except that it is a legal term instead of a job. This person to be hired is not the legal trustee, just a manager who is authorised to do all the work - the legal trustee in this case does not do any work. In today's bloated English, the job is called "fixed asset manager". Today, every job title seems to require three words, such as "chief executive officer".

Comment: _Estate management_ covers real estate, securities, etc. It's not limited to fixed assets, but it applies.

Comment: To nitpick: "civilisation"'s definition isn't well-agreed enough for that kind of claim to be made about "every civilisation in history"; many societies have existed (and, arguably, still exist) without such an asymmetrical wealth distribution that "estate manager" should be a one-word job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some suggestions:

1. (Property) [manager](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/manager)

> a person who conducts business or household affairs

2. (Property) [administrator](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/administrator)

> a person legally vested with the right of administration of an estate

3. [Superintendent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/superintendent)

> one who has executive oversight and charge

or from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superintendent_(construction)):

> a person who represents the owner or principal and administers the contract terms and conditions

Comment: Thank you. I went for "administrator".